# typescript how to do object destructured assignment

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some typescript code which looks like this:

```
transform( payload: object ) {
    const { count = 0, malfunctions = [] } : { count: number, malfunctions: Array<object> } = payload;
}
```

typescript compiler is giving me error:

```
"error TS2322: Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ count: number; malfunctions: object[]; }'."
```

Now I am fairly new to typescript but it seems to me like the compiler is telling me: "you can't assign 'payload' which is an object type to the destructured variables which are of type number and array."

If that is true then how am I supposed to do a destructured assignment in typescript?

Comment: Try `={...payload}` on the right side of your assignment statement.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to extract the properties `count` and `malfunctions`?

Comment: @jpavel - that doesn't work - typescript doesn't seem to allow object rest params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - need to perform the destructure in the parameter:

```
transform( { count = 0, malfunctions = [] } : { count: number, malfunctions: Array<object> } ) {

}
```

Comment: You don't have to "perform the destructure in the parameter", you just have to have the type for the param. The problem was `object` can't be destructured, because it's a vague type. So `transform( payload: { count: number, malfunctions: Array<object> } )` with your original code would work.

Comment: well yes I could do that too but then I'd still have to destructure the object later or access the properties on the object via dot notation right?

Comment: You would destructure like `const { count = 0, malfunctions = [] } = payload` -- again the issue was the use of `object`

Comment: when you say 'const { count = 0, malfunctions = [] } = payload' - thats what i mean by ' I'd still have to destructure the object later'

Comment: Yep, you can destructure in the param assignment or later... but in any case the original error had nothing to do with that.